# ssh2_exec: wait end of a process to run next

Tags: php, ssh

I am running a command using ssh2_exec, but looks like it runs the $stream2 before the end of $stream1 process. How do I run $stream2 only after the end of $stream1?

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$stream1= ssh2_exec($connection, 'command to run');

$stream2 = ssh2_exec($connection, 'command to run 2');

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Problem Solved:**

@Barmar proposed me to look at php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php#59324

I solved the problem by:

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$stream1= ssh2_exec($connection, 'command to run');

stream_set_blocking($stream1, true);

// The command may not finish properly if the stream is not read to end
$output = stream_get_contents($stream1);

$stream2 = ssh2_exec($connection, 'command to run 2');

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

the fact that blocking isn't enabled by default is stupid. this is why i like [SSH by phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net) so much better. stuff just works as expected with phpseclib. eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('shell.example.com', 22);
$ssh->login('username', 'password');

$output = $ssh->exec('command to run');
$ssh->exec('command to run 2');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Read everything from the first stream. When it finishes, you know the command is done.

```
$stream1= ssh2_exec($connection, 'command to run');
stream_get_contents($stream1); // Wait for command to finish
fclose($stream1);

$stream2 = ssh2_exec($connection, 'command to run 2');
```

Comment: Now it is giving me an error on the $stream2 line.

PHP Warning:  ssh2_exec(): Unable to request a channel from remote host in XXX.php on line 28

Comment: And when I remove the line with stream_get_contents, I get no error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with the ssh2 extension to know why that's happening or how to resolve it.

Comment: Try it with the `fclose` I just added. I got the idea from here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php#53691

Comment: If that doesn't work, you may have to resort to the more complicated solution here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php#59324

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I have added the solution in the top of the page.

Comment: You should post it as an answer.