# script doesn't wait for the process end with ssh2_exec and stream_set_blocking

Tags: php, libssh2, ssh2-exec

I have two scripts :

The first one contains the folowing code:

```
<?php
// ...
echo date('H:i:s'), PHP_EOL;
$stream = ssh2_exec($session, 'php my-second-script.php');
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);

$data = "";
while ($buf = fread($stream, 4096)) {
    $data .= $buf;
}

fclose($stream);
echo date('H:i:s'), PHP_EOL;
// ...
```

The second one just contains the following code:

```
<?php
sleep(15);
echo 'OK', PHP_EOL;
```

I don't understand why sometimes when I run my first script, it waits for the second script to run but sometimes no.

For example, when it works I have the following output :

```
14:16:10
14:16:25
```

And sometimes I have this:

```
14:17:13
14:17:14
```

I also read the post [ssh2_exec: wait end of a process to run next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500704/ssh2-exec-wait-end-of-a-process-to-run-next?rq=1) and the guy who answered said that "the command may not finish properly if the stream is not read to end". Someone can explain to me this?